# jQuery ajax call not populating multiple select

Tags: php, ajax, json

Having difficulty getting this to work.  Using Chrome javascript console, I can see that my function is firing and getting the result I nee, it just won't populate the multiple select.  Here's the code:

jQuery:

```
$("select[name='field[one]']").change(function()
        {
            var optionValue = $("select[name='field[one]']").val();
            $.get
            ('/directory/location/getData', {select:optionValue}, 
                function(data) 
                {
                    $("select[name='subjects']").val(data);
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

HTML:

```
<select name="field[one]" id="field_one">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
</select>

<select multiple id="show_results" name="subjects" />
</select>
```

AJAX PHP Call:

```
public function executeGetData(sfWebRequest $request){
     $year = $request->getParameterHolder()->get('select'); 
     $specialties = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Specialty')->getSpecialtyArray();
     $array = array();
     foreach($specialties as $specialty){
         $array[$specialty['id']] = ''; 
         $count = Doctrine_Core::getTable('HistoricalSalaries')->getCountPerSpec($year, $specialty['id']);
         $array[$specialty['id']] .= $specialty['name']." Count($count)"; 
     }
     return $this->renderText( json_encode( $array ) );      
  }
```

The result is a json encoded array... which I think is the problem... getting the multiple select to interpret that info correctly.  Currently nothing happens after the call is made and the data retrieved.

Here is a sample of the json encoded array result shown in chrome debugger:

```
{
 2: "Aerospace Medicine Count(50)",
 3: "Abdominal Radiology (DR) Count(65)",
 4: "Addiction Psychiatry (P) Count(46)",
 5: "Adolescent Medicine (PD) Count(23)"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to iterate through that `data` JSON and create options for the select.

Comment: `field[one]` you gotta avoid using this type of name for your elements as it conflicts with the selector in jquery, for eg in this line `$("select[name='field[one]']").change(function()`.

Comment: these are not the actual names... changed for this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, itemData) {
        var newOption = "<option value='" + index + "'>" + itemData + "</option";
        $("#show_results").append(newOption);
    });
}
```

Here's a fiddle that demo's looping over the JSON: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/8eUFe/

Here's a fiddle demoing your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/8eUFe/1/

Comment: Very close.  This gets all the information in the multiple select, but it is all vertical - one character per line.  Making the the multiple select VERY long.  For some reason, the following characters are included { } along with every " and :

Comment: Not seeing how...used your exact JSON data and it is working in the fiddle?

Comment: ...I know.  I'm obviously not seeing it either.  And yes, your Fiddle works flawlessly (thank you).  Wondering if the JSON data I'm seeing in the console is not the format the data is handed to the function?

Comment: There is a .parseJSON method in jQuery.  Might that be the answer?

Comment: That did it.  Added this line: var obj = $.parseJSON(data); and revised this line: $.each(obj, function(index, itemData) {  work great now.  Thank tymeJV - got me pointed in the right direction.